# Setup Project with LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, setup-deployment, localdb

I have created small demo Windows Application using .NET 4.0. This app uses LocalDB to store/retrieve data. Now I need to create MS Setup file which automatically creates all necessary environment to run my application upon running Setup.exe files. Can somebody answer my following question and provide relevant website for further help?

How do I create Setup File which installs My Windows App along with LocalDB?

What are the prerequisite Microsoft Component to run my application?

How do I secure MDF file? If somebody attach MDF file to SQL Server then hacker can easily see the content of database.

Comment: If you have content in the database then yes it should be considered visible. That means if there is content you need to protect you need to either move to a central database or encrypt the sensitive data at rest.

Comment: OK, I can live with that. I can advise user to move database to secure SQL Server.

Would you like share your experience with my other questions?

Comment: Your other two questions are entirely too broad for a forum post.